# Is this the right way to grab IP when form submitted?

Tags: php, mysqli, ip-address

I did find some info about saving IP and I came up with the code below:

```
// IP GRAB
$http_client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; //MORE RELIABLE IP
$http_x_forwarded_for = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; //ALSO MORE RELIABLE
$remote_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //NOT RELIABLE BCS IT MAY BE A SHARED NETWORK OR BEHIND A PROXY

if (!empty($http_client_ip)) {
    $ip_address = $http_client_ip;
} else if (!empty($http_x_forwarded_for)) {
    $ip_address = $http_x_forwarded_for;
} else {
    $ip_address = $remote_addr;
}

$ip = ip2long($ip_address);
```

I'd like to grab the user's IP address when the user push to submit button/sent form. I also want to save this IP to the table on the database. So I made an IP column on the table as `INT(11) UNSIGNED`(This was recommended for somebody else on here.)

In short: Am I doing it right?

Comment: It looks fine, but I will check all possible methods to get the client ip. I can post a function I use for this reason.

Comment: You're doing it right.

Comment: Right now I have "0"s on my table. How can I actually test this? Do I have to put it on the internet?

Comment: How do you insert the data?

Comment: $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ipTable (IP) VALUES ('$ip')");

of course this query has more columns and variables and others work fine. I will try the remote_addr only but can I trust that if else to grab a accurate ip?

Comment: yes you need to put the code one and test it, i should return your public ip address,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up after some more search:

I changed the `INT(11)UNSIGNED` to `VARCHAR(45)` and I just save IP without using `ip2long();` the rest is the same as it was before. Now it adds `::1` to the `IP` column on the table when I post a test. I assume it works alright and I'll check it out when I actually publish the site.

note: I'll accept this answer when it becomes available. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Thank you. Then I will update the answer and I will accept it when it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can extended, the follow function could be used to get client IP:

```
function get_client_ip() {

    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
}
```

It is also not necessary to change your the IP to long (`ip2long`), only if you have a reason to do it.

And I will save it as String (VARCHAR) in database.

Comment: for some reason I just saw your answer, but I already did something like this so I up-voted your solution too.

-It seems you just undeleted your answer after mine.

Comment: I have mistakenly deleted my answer to edit it and forget to undelete it, sorry for that